# Change column in sql

Tags: sql, select

i have table Match:

```
ID  (int)
ID_Match (int)
ID_Player (int)
Attend   (bit)
Goals (int)
```

When i write

```
Select * from Match
```

i have this:

```
       ID   ID_Match    ID_Player  Attend   Goals
1       69    1            10       1         2
2       70    1            11       0         0
```

And i want have this:

```
ID_Player ID_Match  Attend  Goals
    10       1        1       2
```

Have you some idea?

Comment: `SELECT *` should only be used for prototyping and inside `EXISTS` clauses. Everywhere else, you should be specifically naming the columns you want. And what's the logic in your query - why does row 69 get shown but not row 70?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
select top 1 ID_Player ,ID_Match ,Attend  ,Goals from table_name order by ID asc
```

Comment: Ahmed: Column 'Match.ID_Match' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.